# Cannot uninstall Cuda 9.2 in Windows 10

Tags: cuda, windows-10

Recently installed Cuda Toolkit 9.2 and without paying careful attention that Tensorflow only supports 9.x (which is a bummer). Tried a few times uninstalling it using "Programs and Features" but nothing seems to occur. Exploring NVIDIA developer community did do any good.

[image: Erorr Caption]

Does anyone have a success story on this?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-uninstall-cuda9-0-and-cudnn-under-win10/56314/7)?